# Handling exceptions in .NET (GUI) event functions without excessive boilerplate?

Tags: .net, user-interface, exception, mfc

Note: I don't do .NET programming regularly. Normally I do native/MFC, so I'm a bit lost as how to do this properly in the context of C#.

We're displaying .NET control in the context of a *native* MFC application. That means the GUI thread is a native thread calling into the WndProc of the .NET control. (Well, at least as far as I can tell.)

Obviously, we do *not* want to throw exceptions from our (GUI) event handlers, as there is no proper handler down the call stack that would catch them.

As far as I can tell, the solution(s) with `AppDomain` / `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` do not make sense in a native MFC application. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

So back to the question: How can I avoid having to add a try/catch block to each event handler of the C# control code? Is there some place (System.Forms...Control.WndProc maybe?) where I can catch all .NET exceptions and just display an error dialog to the user?

Comment: Martin a question like yours comes out every now and then, in fact the best thing to do is to handle those exceptions one by one because depending on where you are you know better how to handle it. It's not only about logging or showing a message box is mor about reacting in a different way to different situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce boilerplate code by using a functional approach. Write a function like this:

```
public class Util
{
    public static void SafeCall(Action handler)
    {
      try
      {
           handler();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         // process ex here
      }
}
```

And reuse it in every of your GUI event handlers:

```
void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Util.SafeCall(()=>NameOfYourHandlerMethod(sender,e));
};
```

or

```
void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Util.SafeCall(
    delegate
    {
      // enter code here
    });
};
```

This might need some additional work to get the sender/EventArgs parameters the way you want them, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Nice solution but in SafeCall you don't have access to the original method parameters and you are inside another method so reflection and other stack trace related things are different.

Comment: @Davide Piras: stack trace should not be an issue, you get just one additional level. Parameters can be passed as required (as I already wrote in my post). The biggest difference is that you are not in the GUI class any more, so this solution is mostly applicable if you do some generic error handling. I guess that is what the OP had in mind since his goal is to reduce unneccessary code repetition.